# Facebook Like button does not work

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I checked with the debugger and I have only one warning:

```
The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

And by the way, I cannot find ANYTHING about that property, nor does the Like Button documentation say it's required.

I have the 6 required tags and everything else looks fine. I am using the iframe version of the Like button.

The Like Button displays, can be clicked, then it briefly shows a 1 count and disappears. It does nothing from there. The response from the server is:

`for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":{"requires_login":false,"success":false,"already_connected":false,"is_admin":false,"show_error":true,"error_info":{"brief":"An error has occurred.","full":"There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/tools\/lint\/) and fixing any errors.","errorUri":...`

Comment: Did you run your page through the linter as it suggested?

Comment: Yes, it only has that one warning that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting en_US as the locale meta value.  I'm wondering if Facebook is having a hard time determining what language your page is in.

Comment: That certainly gets rid of the warning but the Like button still acts the same.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to the HTML 5 Like button but I added it dynamically with jQuery instead before the script file is added.

```
var $likeButton = $('<div id="like-button" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-font="lucida grande"/>').addClass('fb-like').attr('data-href', window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/');
$likeButton.insertBefore('.top-toolbar > .toolbar-links');

var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk';
if (document.getElementById(id)) {
  return;
}
js = document.createElement('script');
js.id = id;
js.async = true;
js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
```